# Is it possible to use entity classes and EntityManager without a server?

Tags: java, jpa

In school we learn about jpa. A great method to get and add data to an database. I´m currently on an smal project and do not actually need to build an ebj and a client with Payara/glasfish.. But I would love to use that framework..

Is there a way?

Comment: You will need a server, but it can be an extremely lightweight one. Where are you planning to physically save your data?

Comment: On a remote mysql database.. Any tip of what server I can use?

Comment: JPA does not require JEE.  You can use JPA in any Java SE application.  In JEE, transactions are usually handled automatically by the framework.  In Java SE, therefore, you will need to manage your own transaction boundaries.

Comment: Okay.. How would that be? Like start transaction and end transaction? that kind?

Comment: You *don't* need a server. You can even use an embedded database (a database that runs as part of the process of your application); no separate database server is required in that case.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to do that? Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: @ChristianMoen: If you have to ask, then you may not be ready to do it.  I recommend accessing any of a number of internet-based tutorials on how to use JPA with Java SE, including Oracle's own: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SettingUpJPA/SettingUpJPA.htm

Comment: Thank you for your assist. I will look up on that!

Comment: @Jesper From the perspective of the application, even H2 appears as a server.

Comment: H2 is a database! He clearly refers to Payara type servers ... Java EE ... which you do NOT need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an implementation of JPA, such as [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) in any Java application, it doesn't need to be a Java EE app that runs in an application server such as Payara or Glassfish.

Comment: will this support an remote mysql database?

Comment: Yes, it will support any database, local or remote, the same as in a webapp running in a server.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Will that be an server that needs to be running on the clients machine?

Comment: No, you can also use an embedded database such as [h2database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/).